# TYPO3 maximum file size for filelist?

Tags: typo3

In my TYPO3 installation only files up to (2GB?) are shown in the filelist.

[image]

But there are more files over 2GB in the folder (see screen ftp) - how can I view these?

[image]

Comment: Looks like the end of a database INT-field for bytes, which is (signed) 2147483647... Not sure, where this causes a problem, but the numbers seem to match.

Comment: Seems not to be database issue, but PHP. PHPs `filesize()` return only an INT...

Answer (score 0):

Were all files uploaded via the TYPO3 Backend or maybe via FTP, SCP, etc.?

You could try to run the Scheduler Task "File Abstraction Layer: Update storage index" to update the index/cache data of your storage.